# EJSONPARSE package.json running npm task

Tags: json, node.js, npm

```
npm ERR! code EJSONPARSE
npm ERR! Failed to parse json
npm ERR! Unexpected token ':' at 1:10
npm ERR! "scripts": {
npm ERR!          ^
npm ERR! File: C:\Users\Desktop\temp\jest\package.json
npm ERR! Failed to parse package.json data.
npm ERR! package.json must be actual JSON, not just JavaScript.
```

I have this

```
"scripts": {
  "test": "jest"
}
```

in my package.json, then I do npm test, I got strange error above, what's wrong? I follow exactly the steps here http://facebook.github.io/jest/docs/getting-started.html

Comment: Can you please post the entirety of your package.json (as-is)?

Comment: You need to have an existing package.json file first. You can use `npm init` to initialize your package.json file, then copy the above in that file.